# SSLSNIFF on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, ssl

I tried to install sslsniff 0.8 on CentOS 7 but I can't install the following dependencies since they can't be found when I execute the "yum" command: `libboost1.35-dev, libboost-filesystem1.35-dev, libboost-thread1.35-dev`.

I tried "yum install libboost*" and it installed the following packages:

```
 Installation :
 boost-atomic                      x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base           34 k
 boost-chrono                      x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base           43 k
 boost-context                     x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base           36 k
 boost-filesystem                  x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base           67 k
 boost-graph                       x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          135 k
 boost-graph-mpich                 x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base           87 k
 boost-graph-openmpi               x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          102 k
 boost-locale                      x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          250 k
 boost-math                        x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          334 k
 boost-mpich                       x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base           60 k
 boost-mpich-python                x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          183 k
 boost-openmpi                     x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base           74 k
 boost-openmpi-python              x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          205 k
 boost-program-options             x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          155 k
 boost-python                      x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          132 k
 boost-random                      x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base           38 k
 boost-regex                       x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          294 k
 boost-serialization               x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          170 k
 boost-signals                     x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base           60 k
 boost-test                        x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          226 k
 boost-timer                       x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base           42 k
 boost-wave                        x86_64          1.53.0-25.el7                     base          211 k
 boost148-chrono                   x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           18 k
 boost148-date-time                x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           24 k
 boost148-filesystem               x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           50 k
 boost148-graph                    x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           67 k
 boost148-graph-mpich              x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           65 k
 boost148-graph-openmpi            x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           82 k
 boost148-iostreams                x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           34 k
 boost148-locale                   x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel          219 k
 boost148-math                     x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel          267 k
 boost148-mpich                    x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           36 k
 boost148-mpich-python             x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           15 k
 boost148-openmpi                  x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           60 k
 boost148-openmpi-python           x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           31 k
 boost148-program-options          x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel          115 k
 boost148-python                   x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel          105 k
 boost148-random                   x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           12 k
 boost148-regex                    x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel          271 k
 boost148-serialization            x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel          143 k
 boost148-signals                  x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           33 k
 boost148-system                   x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           13 k
 boost148-test                     x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel          201 k
 boost148-thread                   x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           32 k
 boost148-timer                    x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel           16 k
 boost148-wave                     x86_64          1.48.0-7.el7                      epel          171 k
Installation pour dépendances :
 compat-openmpi16                  x86_64          1.6.4-10.el7                      base          2.5 M
 environment-modules               x86_64          3.2.10-10.el7                     base          107 k
 hwloc-libs                        x86_64          1.7-5.el7                         base          1.3 M
 infinipath-psm                    x86_64          3.3-0.g6f42cdb1bb8.2.el7          base          176 k
 libesmtp                          x86_64          1.0.6-7.el7                       base           63 k
 libfabric                         x86_64          1.1.0-2.el7                       base          215 k
 libibumad                         x86_64          1.3.10.2-1.el7                    base           66 k
 libpsm2                           x86_64          0.7-4.el7                         base          164 k
 mpich                             x86_64          3.0.4-8.el7                       base          1.0 M
 openmpi                           x86_64          1.10.0-10.el7                     base          3.0 M
 opensm-libs                       x86_64          3.3.19-1.el7                      base           65 k
 tcl                               x86_64          1:8.5.13-8.el7                    base          1.9 M
```

But then when I tried to run ./configure inside the unzipped sslsniff package, I got this:

```
...
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking log4cpp/Category.hh usability... yes
checking log4cpp/Category.hh presence... yes
checking for log4cpp/Category.hh... yes
checking boost/asio.hpp usability... no
checking boost/asio.hpp presence... no
checking for boost/asio.hpp... no
configure: error: libboost1.35-dev library is not installed.
```

Can someone please help me with this ? Maybe there's no sslsniff version on CentOS and I need some other equivalent package... ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

sslsniff [hasn't been updated](https://github.com/moxie0/sslsniff) since the end of 2011. Author seems to ignore issues and pull requests.

You have a few options:

- look through forks on GitHub to see if anyone is keeping it all up to date;
- try and find libboost 1.35 for Centos (or maybe even compile it yourself) and build against that;
- depending on your needs, [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) might fit your usecase.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! I actually tried to find libboost 1.35 for CentOS but with no success. I'll give a try to mitmproxy.